# Storing output of System.currentTimeMillis() in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, timespan

I am using System.currentTimeMillis(); funtion in java to compute time taken by a program. I have to run my program for 10 iterations and report the average results. If I store the output of System.currentTimeMillis(); function as double will it be acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a long, which requires 8 bytes. And if you want to store that value in mysql then equivalent will be BIGINT, which is also 8 bytes.

References:

**Java**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

**MySQL**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Computed average maybe a decimal value and hence only average needs to be of type `double`.

Comment: Since I am computing average and standard deviation I need some data type which accepts decimal values. Hence, I am thinking to store it in double. Please let me know if its fine.

Comment: @Sangeeta The value is in *milliseconds*, so any fraction for a average value will be in fractions of *milliseconds*. Do you truly need that kind of precision for an *average* value?

Comment: It is a research project so I want to report the best possible thing.

Comment: @Sangeeta Only average needs to be of type double then